# Python regex to find time, years, weeks and days from a line

Tags: regex, python-3.x

My data looks like as give below and I need to capture either the time or the years, weeks and days from it using a regex:

```
10.174.17.32/29 [20/0] via 10.174.30.129, `18years2weeks3days`, somedata 

10.174.17.32/29 [20/0] via 10.174.30.129, `18y2w3d`, somedata

10.174.17.32/29 [20/0] via 10.174.30.129, `7w0d`, somedata

10.174.17.32/29 [20/0] via 10.174.30.129, `366days`, somedata

10.174.17.32/29 is directly connected, `12:46:02`, somedata

10.174.17.32/29 [20/0] via 10.174.30.129, `00:00:56`, somedata
```

I wrote this regex in Python:

```
res = re.compile(r'[0-9]{0,3}[a-zA-Z]{0,5}[0-9]{0,2}[a-zA-Z]{0,5}[0-9]{0,3}[a-zA-Z]{0,4}')
```

But this regex catches a lot of unwanted stuff too. I just need to catch either the time or the word with years, weeks and days.

I'd be happy if this can be done using two regexs, if there's one regex which can do so it would be great! The length of the data may vary with more unwanted stuff before or after the data that I'm trying to capture. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex parses the rows for years, weeks, days and time ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/CjpPvR/1)):

```
data = '''

10.174.17.32/29 [20/0] via 10.174.30.129, 18years2weeks3days, somedata

10.174.17.32/29 [20/0] via 10.174.30.129, 18y2w3d, somedata

10.174.17.32/29 [20/0] via 10.174.30.129, 7w0d, somedata

10.174.17.32/29 [20/0] via 10.174.30.129, 366days, somedata

10.174.17.32/29 is directly connected, 12:46:02, somedata

10.174.17.32/29 [20/0] via 10.174.30.129, 00:00:56, somedata'''

import re

print('{:^15} {:^15} {:^15} {:^15}'.format('Years', 'Weeks', 'Days', 'Time'))
for years, weeks, days, time in re.findall(r'(?:(\d+)y(?:ears?)?)?(?:(\d+)w(?:eeks?)?)?(\d+)d(?:ays?)?|(\d+:\d+:\d+)', data):
    print('{:^15} {:^15} {:^15} {:^15}'.format(years, weeks, days, time))
```

Prints:

```
 Years           Weeks           Days            Time      
  18               2               3                       
  18               2               3                       
                   7               0                       
                                  366                      
                                               12:46:02    
                                               00:00:56
```

Comment: Works like a charm!!! Thank you very much @Andrej :) Would you mind explaining the regex a bit? Thanks again!

Comment: @VivekSingh The regex is creating 4 capturing groups, first three groups are in style `(?:(\d+)y(?:ears?)?)?` - number, following one letter (y, w or d) and then optional letters (ears, eeks, ays), 4th group captures time. When you click https://regex101.com/r/CjpPvR/1 there's detailed explanation on the right side.